# POST JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json

```
def post():
    url = "someurl.com"
    with open(jsonfile) as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            post_fields = line
            print(post_fields)
            request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())
            json = urlopen(request).read().decode()
            print(json)


post()
```

I am trying to post my JSON data to a website using the code above. However, I met up with an error. The error is

> not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object

Below is my JSON data.

```
[{"ContentUrl": "https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/871331574649901056", "Text": "Do you notice we are not having a gun debate right now? That's because they used knives and a truck!", "PublishDate": "4:43 AM - 4 Jun 2017", "Title": "", "SourceUrl": "https://twitter.com/@realDonaldTrump", "SocialNetwork": "Twitter", "Source": "", "Author": "Donald J. Trump", "Like_count": "147,875 likes", "Replies_count": "57,397 replies", "Retweets_count": "45,500 retweets", "Schema": "SOCIAL_MEDIA"}]
```

Any help or suggestions for me?

Comment: Is the json line that you gave, a line in `my file`?

Comment: yes it is @saloua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my comments:

- You need to precise what is the payload part that you want to post to the url.
- You need to decode the json objects from each line by using `json.loads`

According to your answer to my question the json file contains the following.

> [{"ContentUrl": "https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/871331574649901056", "Text": "Do you notice we are not having a gun debate right now? That's because they used knives and a truck!", "PublishDate": "4:43 AM - 4 Jun 2017", "Title": "", "SourceUrl": "https://twitter.com/@realDonaldTrump", "SocialNetwork": "Twitter", "Source": "", "Author": "Donald J. Trump", "Like_count": "147,875 likes", "Replies_count": "57,397 replies", "Retweets_count": "45,500 retweets", "Schema": "SOCIAL_MEDIA"}]

Then, which part of the dictionary is the payload that you want to use in the post request ?

Here is the fixed code. But you still need to precise the right `url` and `payload` you want to use.

```
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib import urlopen
from requests import Request
import json
import requests

def post(jsonfile):
    with open(jsonfile) as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            # Decoding JSON object
            json_data = json.loads(line)
            # Here you need to iterate over the json_data as it is an array
            for el in json_data:
                url = el["ContentUrl"]
                el.pop("ContentUrl")
                # Here I use the rest of the fields in el as payload
                # But I don't think that you are using the right data
                # You still need to find out which payload you want to send in the post request
                response = requests.post(url, data = el)
                print(response.status_code, response.reason)

jsonfile='testfile.json'
post(jsonfile)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help! Just want to ask 2 questions. What does el and el.pop do? What if the whole chunk were suppose to be used in the POST request? As i am currently using a .txt file to store all of my JSON data as a list, every JSON data in the list is considered as one, and will be used as a whole. So i am not really sure what i am suppose to do.

Comment: I have tried again using a .json file and i receive an error.                      
 `not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object` @saloua

Comment: `el.pop` removes the key `ContentUrl` and its related value from the dictionary. It is just used to get all the dictionary data except the url part. As your need is not very clear which part you want to use as payload to post. just tried with that part of the dictionary. @NewbieCoder. If you want to use the whole dictionary, then you just need to remove the line with `el.pop`

Comment: The change of the file extension `.json` should have no effect on your code. @NewbieCoder

Answer (score 0):

```
def post():
    url = "someurl.com"
    with open(jsonfile) as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            json_data = json.loads(line)
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(json_data))
    print(response.status_code, response.reason)

post()
```

I tried combining methods i see from around the net and this finally work for me.